# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `defaultSelected` supplied to `TypeaheadContainer(WrappedTypeahead)`

Tags: reactjs, typeahead, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I'm passing the selected item as a prop to my component that utilizes react-bootstrap-typeahead as well as loading the options in the componentDidUpdate method of this component. I'm trying to conditionally add the 'defaultSelected' property as it seemed to fail when the options weren't loaded yet but I still get this error:

Failed prop type: Invalid prop `defaultSelected` supplied to `TypeaheadContainer(WrappedTypeahead)`

The selectedCourier is set from the props which is an object that matches up with one of the options returned from the GET couriers response. Any help?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        step: props.step,
        selectedCourier: props.step.courier && props.step.courier.courierId ? props.step.courier : null,
        submitMessage: props.step.courier && props.step.courier.submitMessage ? props.step.courier.submitMessage : '',
        couriers: []
    };
}

componentDidMount = () => {
    nprogress.start();
    nprogress.configure({showSpinner: false, easing: 'ease', speed: 500});
    axios
        .get('/Couriers')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(this.state);
            this.setState({couriers: response.data});
            nprogress.done()
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            nprogress.done()
        });
    console.log(this.state);
};

render() {
    var inputProps = {};

    if (this.state.selectedCourier != null && this.state.couriers.length > 0) {
        inputProps.defaultSelected = this.state.selectedCourier
    }
    return (
...
<Typeahead
 onInputChange={this.handleCourierSearchChange}
 labelKey="name"
 options={this.state.couriers}
 placeholder="Search couriers..."
 onChange={selected => {
     this.selectCourier(selected);
 }}
 id="courierSearch"
 ref={(ref) => this._typeaheadCouriers = ref}
 {...inputProps}
/>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `defaultSelected` and `selected` expect an array, but it looks like `props.step.courier` is an object. Try the following when defining your state:

```
this.state = {
  ...
  selectedCourier: props.step.courier && props.step.courier.courierId ? [props.step.courier] : [],
};
```

You also most likely want to use `selected` instead of `defaultSelected`, since it looks like this is a controlled component. `defaultSelected` won't be set or changed after the initial mount, but you're trying to update the selections when the set of options is populated.